# Is the Asus Z97 Board integrated Graphics or iGPU, and what is the difference?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, gpu

I plan to buy an [Asus Sabertooth Z97 Mark 1](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/SABERTOOTH_Z97_MARK_1/HelpDesk_CPU/) board, with an [Intel Xeon Processor E3-1220 v3](http://ark.intel.com/products/75052/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1220-v3-8M-Cache-3_10-GHz) (without graphic). Now I don't know if the Asus board uses an integrated graphics or the graphics from my CPU, in the comp-list the CPU is listed, but there is no info about the graphics.

Can anyone explain the iGPU and integrated graphics difference? This is a block diagram of the Z97 chipset, I can't find integrated graphics.

[image: Block diagram of the Z97 chipset]

Comment: Essentially its identical to this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/802233/when-will-i-need-a-display-card/802243#802243) Essentially the GPU is *on* the cpu die in most core i3/5/7 mainstream processors, and the equivilent xeons *do not have* onboard graphics. You *need* on die graphics in the cpu you select for the 'integral' ports to work. Else you need a discrete, pci-e gpu

Answer (score 1):

iGPU stands for Integrated Graphics Processing Unit.

**Integrated:**

An integrated graphics processing unit (GPU) doesn't use its own RAM; it utilizes the system's memory instead.

**Dedicated:**

A dedicated, or discrete, GPU has its own independent source of video memory, leaving the RAM your system uses untouched.

According to the [**asus sabertooth z97 mark 1**](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/SABERTOOTH_Z97_MARK_1/specifications/) specs, it does have an Integrated Graphics Processing Unit:

[image]
[image]

The CPU, working in conjunction with software applications, sends information about the image to the graphics card or Integrated Graphics Processing Unit.  The graphics card/Integrated Graphics Processing Unit then decides how to use the pixels on the screen to create the image. It then sends that information to the monitor through a cable. ­

So with that motherboard and CPU, if you were to plug a monitor into the HDMI port it would work/function as expected.

Comment: but in the block diagram is shown that the chipset use the CPU integrated Graphic. So the most CPUs that can be used in the Z97 chipset has a integrated Graphic but this one not. The remark in the comp-list mean that is a Server CPU and some integrated features not available?

Comment: Now I'am confused, it is right that I need a Videocard or not?

Comment: @kockiren , simply say, yes, you need a video card for the Z97 motherboards. You can simply assume Z97 boards has no display functions (they are having only the ports). So you either go with a CPU with GPU, or display cards.